# Is it possible to read streaming response body using fiber?

Tags: go, ffmpeg, stream, httpserver, go-fiber

I have a streaming server(ffmpeg) that send data through **HTTP**.
I sent the stream to my [fiber](https://gofiber.io/) backend but I only have access to `c.body()` when the stream server(ffmpeg) is terminated.
Is there any way to capture streamed data in **real-time** in fiber?

here is my sample code:

```golang
package main

import "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"

func main() {
  app := fiber.New()
  
app.Post("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    golang        // real-time reading streamed data in c.body() and send it to fiber websocket
        return c.SendStatus(200)

}
```

Comment: net/http allows this without any problems. You might want to reconsider your choice of HTTP implementation if this turns out to be a problem.

Comment: is net/http fast as mush as fiber?
do you have any example code of it?@Volker

Comment: net/http is not as fast as fasthttp but you are asking about a streaming solution where speed is limited by the network, not the HTTP implementation. Most people vastly overerstimate how much "perfoemance" they gain by using fasthttp. If your application is 0..7% slower and spends 3% more in GC: Would this really matter?

Comment: Have you measured performance problems with `net/http`? The http implementation is rarely the bottleneck. What does it matter if fiber is theoretically faster than some other framework using `net/http` if it's not what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want can be found in `c.Context()` - this returns the FastHTTP context that Fiber uses under the hood.

The FastHTTP context has at least 2 functions which sound like they're what you're after: `SetBodyStream` and `SetBodyStreamWriter`.

[Related fiber docs](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/ctx#context)

[FastHTTP docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestCtx.SetBodyStream)